# Webview ShouldOverrideUrlLoading not called

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview like the below given code, i am trying to catch the redirect url on login inside the webview, so i have used ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method but the control never comes inside this method.

I have read other answers related to this and tried few things like using webView.loadDataWithBaseURL the webview went blank and trying to use chromeclient and catching the url but this works only on first load not on redirecting.

what might be the issue?

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loginwebview);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/CustomerActivation");

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearView();
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
    }
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
             {
                Log.d("url",url);
                if (url.contains("account-secured/dashboard")){
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
               }else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
            }


            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your links are local try adding an `app://` prefix or equivalent.

From [Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

> For example, the new WebView may not call your shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method for links like this:
>
> ```
> <a href="showProfile">Show Profile</a>
> ```
>
> Instead of using a simple string in a link as shown above, you can use
>   a custom scheme such as the following:
>
> ```
> <a href="example-app:showProfile">Show Profile</a>
> ```

This worked for me when I changed the link from `<a href="#4">` to `<a href="app://4">`.

```
class MyWebViewClient(val activity: AppCompatActivity) : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        activity.findViewById<RadioButton>(AMAinActivity.primaryButtons[3]).performClick()
        return true
    }
}
```

Note that the method works even though it is deprecated.

To intercept your link click specify the link with its full path i.e. `<a href="https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/CustomerActivation"`>:-

Comment: in showProfile where is the base url? can you help  me with this url https://www.xfinityprepaid.net/CustomerActivation/CustomerActivation  how to put this in <a href> ?

Answer (score -1):

Try overriding onReceivedSslError.